# Unable to review close votes

Tags: bug, close-votes

I'm not quite sure why this is, but when I try to review close votes, the only option I have is 'Skip.'  A screenshot:

[image]

Is this because of my low rep?

Comment: It's more likely because you're run out of close votes for the day. For a private beta, that priv is set at 1 rep.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk I haven't used any at all on this site yet.  I haven't been able to.

Comment: Are you out of normal votes?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk, not by a long shot.  Only used a dozen at most so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, there's a check that runs to see if you have access to the various options before giving them to you...

- It checks if you have full editing rights before giving you the Edit button. [You don't have full editing rights](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), so you didn't get the edit button.
- It checks a whole bunch of privileges before giving you access to the Close and Leave Open buttons... It checks for the [Close/Reopen](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege of course, but before it checks that it checks the [Flag Posts](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) privilege. And with 5 rep on a private beta site, you have the former but not the latter.

This is one of those weird things that *only* happens in private betas, because *everywhere else* you earn the ability to flag *long* before you get close and reopen votes. Arguably, flagging should be a 1-rep privilege here too, but... There's some really grim potential for abuse with that and so we cannot lower the rep-threshold for that privilege.

The proper fix here is probably to check the [access review queues](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege before letting you into *any* review queue. Failing that, blocking access to the Close and Reopen queues until you have both Close/Reopen *and* Flag privileges would suffice.